# Hints on getting basic arithmetic expressions to be parsed in Swift

Tags: swift

Consider the following expression:

```
 let N = 2048
 var c = (0..<N).map{ f ->  Float in sin( 2 * .pi * f / (N/2)) }
```

`Swift` can not really parse it:

[image]

This is *already* a very small expression: it's absurd to break it into even smaller pieces.  So I am trying to use type-casts. But I am getting weary of adding many explicit type casts :

```
    let N = 2048
    var c: [Float] = (0..<N).map{ f ->  Float in
        Float(sin( 2.0 * .pi * f / (Float(N/2)))) }
```

Even with the above the error continues

[image]

Why is `swift` so weak in parsing these simple arithmetic expressions? What can I do short of breaking it into pieces of the form

```
 let c = a * b
 let f = c * d
```

That is just too simplistic to be practical for signal processing. I am guessing that there were tricks to get the compiler to be a bit more intelligent: please do share.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that the arithmetic operators (`+`,`-`,`*` and `/`) have *a lot* of overloads. Hence, when you write expressions containing a lot of those operators, the compiler cannot resolve them in time.

This is especially true when you have type errors. The compiler tries to find the correct overload, but cannot do so, since your types are mismatching and there's no matching overload. However, by the time the compiler could infer this, it's already past the timeout for resolving expressions and hence you get that error instead of the actual type error.

As soon as you resolve the type errors by casting all `Int`s to `Float`, the single line expression compiles just fine.

```
let c = (0..<N).map{ f ->  Float in sin( 2 * .pi * Float(f) / Float(N/2)) }
```

Once you do that, you don't even need the named closure argument and type annotation of the return value anymore.

```
let c = (0..<N).map{ sin(2 * .pi * Float($0) / Float(N/2)) }
```

Comment: oh I see what happened - i missed the loop variable `$0` . Whereas some of the other type hints and casts were unnecessary.  So I feel more comfortable about how to go about this next time. Thx

Comment: This is unfortunately really  brittle.  I simply changed the `sin(2.0` (instead of `sin(2` and it gave "unable to resolve types in reasonable time"

Comment: @javadba as I've said, the arithmetic operators have a ton of overloads, so writing complex arithmetic expressions can fail easily if you mess up the types. It's best to split those expressions up first to get all the types right and once that's done, you can simplify the expression.

Comment: I'm just a bit agape at this - which other language is so tricky  to write an expression.  Breaking an expression into _tiny_ sound bites  is not happening because then it reads poorly.  Instead  I am cataloguing these "requirements".  I did a `typealias Fl = Float` to help a tiny bit with the noise.  This is not a _general_ indictment:  swift is nicer language than a couple of others that come to mind .

Answer (score 1):

That looks like java. What about

```
 let N = 2048
 var c = (0..<N).map{ f in 
     sin( 2.0 * .pi * Float(f) / Float(N/2))
  }
```

Comment: I had started with _zero_ casts and type hints and started adding one at a time. I thought I had had exactly what you show above at some point. I do not understand exactly what the compiler were getting tripped up on ;)

Comment: Ah I see now what I had missed: specifically the `Float(f)` loop variable casting from `Int` to `Float`.

Comment: I am getting repeatedly stopped or seriously slowed down here.  No other language I have used is so weak in parsing basic arithmetic.